# Java convert to English to Piglatin using array

Tags: java, string

i want to write a program to convert English to Piglantin using Java,but unlike the traditional way i want to store the vowels in an array...but apparently that doesn't work,i have my boards tomorrow and it would be quite helpful if you could point out my mistake....here's the program snippet

```
class Piglatin_2
{

    public static void main(String s)
    {
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        char c[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
        String a = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
               if(s.charAt(i) == c[j])
               {
                   a = s.substring(i) + s.substring(0, i) + "AY";
                   break;
               }
            }
       }
       System.out.println("Piglatin:"+a);
    }
}
```

I am using the string "London" as an input.
The supposed output should be "ONDONLAY"
But i am getting "ONLONDAY"

Comment: Firstly, a main method must take an array of strings, not just one.

Comment: Is your algorithm supposed to translate sentences, or just words?

Comment: i want to translate just words

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean?  Is there an error?  Please provide sample input, expected output, and actual output.  Did you try debugging? Or simpler, walk through the code on paper.

Comment: ah ok sorry,editing the question

Comment: Hint: copy `System.out.println("Piglatin:"+a);` to before the `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you `break`, you have to break out of both loops.  Right now your `break` statement only breaks out of the inner loop.  Try this:

```
public static void main_other(String s)
{
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    char c[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
    String a = "";
    outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
           if(s.charAt(i) == c[j])
           {
               a = s.substring(i) + s.substring(0, i) + "AY";
               break outerloop;
           }
        }
   }
   System.out.println("Piglatin:"+a);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!Thank you man...tommorow's my board,i really needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your main method has to take an array of strings, like Michael's comment says. This will work in your favor as well if you are trying to translate each word. If you run your program with a sentence as arguments, the your args[] array will contain each word that is split by white space. For instance, if your sentence is "Hello World" and you run it with

```
$ java -jar myapplication.jar hello world
```

then your args array will look like

```
args[0] = hello
args[1] = world
```

from there you should be able to iterate though the array and translate each word to pig latin.

[OPINION] If you're just wanting to have a script to pass a sentence to and return pig latin, using Java is kind of line landing a 747 on the freeway. You may want to use something like python or even a shell script if you're using unix. Otherwise, you may consider having a loop that keeps the program running and taking input with a BufferedReader and that way you can keep translating sentences until you end the program.

Comment: Thank you Ben,but i need this for my National board exams,so using another language is not possible,i have found the solution,but thanks again for sharing your experience and knowledge.